# Select an element inside a span which is inside a Div using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on converting a Selenium Test Suite from Java to Python. One of our helper methods uses the following code

```
public String associateCustomSegmentToCampaign(String suffix, int segIndex)
    {
        waitForElement("#tab-custom","#tab-custom");
        waitForElement("#custom-segments divItemSegments" + segIndex, ".tab--box");

        String segCode = "CustomSeg" + suffix;

        List<FluentWebElement> fluentWebElements = $("li");
        for(FluentWebElement fluentWebElement:fluentWebElements)
        {
            if(fluentWebElement.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("tab-custom"))
            {

                waitForElement("#tab-custom", ".tab--inactive");

                click("#tab-custom");

                click("#custom-segments #divItemSegments" + segIndex + " .fa-plus-circle");
                //fill("#txtSegCode" + segCodeIndex).with(segCode);
            }
        }

        return segCode;
    }
```

I am struggling to convert the line

```
click("#custom-segments #divItemSegments" + segIndex + " .fa-plus-circle");
```

into Python

Any help appreciated

Comment: what is click ? can you share the code for the same ?

Comment: Its the function which accepts the string argument, identifies the element corresponding to it and clicks it

Comment: Yes  that I understand , could you share the code of click method ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?  It's not clear from your question what problem you are trying to solve.  Does the click() method fail with an exception?  Or are you just having difficulty constructing the string to pass into the method?

Comment: the click() is a built-in function for fluent-selenium.

My problem was something completely different. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

the string is a css selector. in python it would look like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#custom-segments #divItemSegments" + segIndex + " .fa-plus-circle").click()
```